# Is it possible to create a shirokuro puzzle and publish it without infringing copyright?

Tags: puzzle-creation

I have seen some online [shirokuro](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/html/cros7shkr.htm) games, and I guess new ones are created by code every day. Hence my question: if I create one myself, can I publish it somewhere without infringing copyright? Because I can't possibly check if my creation has been already created at some point in the past.

Comment: Its a tricky situation thats never really got a definitive answer - its more discussed regarding sudokus, and from reading online it seems to boil down to if the publisher's claimed copyright - which is unlikely to be challenged. *However* - shirokuro was invented by Nikoli, who invented sudoku, and [according to CBS](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/life-after-sudoku-and-still-no-trademarks/) they have decided to not trademark sudoku or any other puzzles, quote 'Nikoli does not plan to trademark other new games, either, in hopes this will also help them take off.' - so you should be fine.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Note, though, that trademark (whether you can use the name shikokuro without permission from Nikoli) is a completely separate issue from copyright (whether you can publish a specific puzzle created by someone else without permission from that person).

Comment: I'd be more worried about patent and trademark than copyright.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

I searched Law Stack Exchange for related questions and found this one with a relevant answer: "[Is a randomly-generated book a violation of copyright?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1989)". The key section is reproduced below.

> Copyright infringement requires that you actually **copy** elements from an earlier work produced by a different author. If you created a similar, or even identical, work independently, it is not copyright infringement.
>
> When considering whether or not infringement has occurred, the court is likely to consider whether the defendant could reasonably have had access to the plaintiff's work. If the court finds that they could have, then the defendant would be required to produce evidence of original authorship.

As with any work, reasonable checks should be made to ensure you're not copying protected works, but there's not much that can feasibly be done to search for a specific grid arrangement.

Therefore you're probably fine. Of course you could be sued (anyone can be sued for anything!) but a court should be unlikely to find you copied unless you *copied*. That is, if it's reasonable to assume you haven't seen this specific puzzle before, and were thus unable to copy consciously or subconsciously, you didn't violate copyright.

If you are worried about copyright claims, I suggest **saving intermediate stages** of the puzzle-making process: boards that are partially filled, or slightly broken, created in the process of making the final puzzle. This should strengthen your claim that you independently created the puzzle.

Comment: I was typing out a similar answer, but this covers it well. Also, it may of course be difficult to *show* you created the puzzle independently if the end result is extremely similar to an earlier work, but honestly the issue is vanishingly unlikely to arise since there are a massive number of possible shirokuro puzzles.

Comment: @Jafe I have added a suggestion as to how to show you made the puzzle independently.

Comment: providing source code, and the seed for a crypographic RNG that produces the puzzle should convince all expert witnesses that you created it

Comment: @Jasen If it's a cryptographically-*secure* PRNG, yes. If it's something like Mersenne Twister, and the seed is large enough, no.